# how to select set of records is ID is present in one of them

Tags: sql, oracle, postgresql

Here is the table where ORGID/USERID makes unique combination:

```
ORGID   USERID
1       1
1       2
1       3
1       4
2       1
2       5
2       6
2       7
3       9
3       10
3       11
```

I need to select all records (organizations and users) wherever USERID 1 is present. So USERID=1 is present in ORGID 1 and 2 so then select all users for these organizations including user 1 itself, i.e.

```
ORGID   USERID
1       1
1       2
1       3
1       4
2       1
2       5
2       6
2       7
```

Is it possible to do it with one SQL query rather than SELECT *.. WHERE USERID IN (SELECT...

Comment: Postgres or Oracle? Please tag only one database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you **can** do it with a single `select` statement - no `in` or `exists` conditions, no analytic or aggregate functions in a subquery, etc. **Why** you want to do it that way is not clear; in any case, it is possible that the solution below is also more efficient than the alternatives. You will have to test on your real-life data to see if that is true.

The solution below has two potential disadvantages: it only works in Oracle (it uses a proprietary extension of SQL, the `match_recognize` clause); and it only works in Oracle 12.1 or higher.

```
with
  my_table(orgid, userid) as (
    select 1,  1 from dual union all
    select 1,  2 from dual union all
    select 1,  3 from dual union all
    select 1,  4 from dual union all
    select 2,  1 from dual union all
    select 2,  5 from dual union all
    select 2,  6 from dual union all
    select 2,  7 from dual union all
    select 3,  9 from dual union all
    select 3, 10 from dual union all
    select 3, 11 from dual
  )
-- End of SIMULATED data (for testing), not part of the solution.
-- In real life you don't need the WITH clause; reference your actual table.
select *
from   my_table
match_recognize(
  partition by orgid
  all rows per match
  pattern (x* a x*)
  define  a as userid = 1
);
```

Output:

```
     ORGID     USERID
---------- ----------
         1          1
         1          2
         1          3
         1          4
         2          1
         2          5
         2          7
         2          6
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `exists`:

```
select *
from mytable t
where exists (select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.orgid = t.orgid and t1.userid = 1)
```

Another option is window functions. In Postgres:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        bool_or(userid = 1) over(partition by orgid) has_user_1
    from mytable t
) t
where has_user_1
```

Or a more generic approach, that uses portable expressions:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*,
        max(case when userid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by orgid) has_user_1
    from mytable t
) t
where has_user_1 = 1
```

Comment: that's all good but I'm asking if it can be possible with one select .. or group data somehow

Comment: @VladP: the answer lists available solution. One way or another, you need a subquery to solve such problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `exists`:

```
select ou.*
from orguser ou
where exists (select 1
              from orguser ou ou2
              where ou2.orgid = ou.orgid and ou2.userid = 1
             );
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `Exists` and windows function, you can use `IN` as follows:

```
select *
  from your_table t
 where t.orgid in (select t1.orgid from your_table t1 where t1.userid = 1)
```